# Getting the size of a folder in Java returns negative long

Tags: java, file, recursion, size

I am trying to get the length (file size) of a directory and I have made the following recursive method to do so, only I get some very strange results when I  pass `new File("C:\\Users\\UserName\\Desktop")` as the parameter.

```
static long totalLength = 0;

// Method to get the size of a folder and its contents
private static long getFolderSize(File folder){
    if(folder.isDirectory()){
        File[] contents = folder.listFiles();
        for(File current : contents){
            if(current.isDirectory()){
                totalLength = totalLength +getFolderSize(current);
            }
            totalLength = totalLength + current.length();
        }
    }
    return totalLength;
}
```

Interestingly though, some folders on my desktop do return the expected results when I pass them into the method. I just can't work out why either: I've done some debugging of the length of the individual files and none of them appear to be negative, but I still sometimes get negative results!

Any ideas would be appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't you want an `else` around the `totalLength = totalLength + current.length()` block?

Comment: Something is missing from the above code, the `getFolderSize()` method  receives one or two parameters? is it overloaded?

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I don't know what you mean. The method is not overloaded and it only has one parameter. Why are you confused?

Comment: @Andy Look at the code you posted: the method definition of `getFolderSize()` receives one parameter, `folder`. But when you call it, you're passing two parameters, `current` and `initial`.

Comment: Also, it's a terrible idea storing the result in a `static long int`, you're never clearing it between calls (setting it again to zero).

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Oh, I see, sorry about that. I added that parameter initially but then depreciated it's use so when I posted the code I deleted all references to it, but obviously failed to delete that one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use an established library which already has this built in, such as:

- http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#sizeOfDirectory(java.io.File)

Which also has tests to cover cases like this.

Comment: In answer to YOUR question, because I wasn't really aware of the FileUtils library. I'm now using it and it works a treat so thanks a bunch!

Comment: icyrock.com, just one more questions. This method seems a tad slow when computing the size of, say a 20 GB folder, so are there alternatives or can I do anything to speed it up etc. ?

Comment: The slowness doesn't come from the size of the folder, rather the number of subfolders and files - if you had 20 1GB files, it would be super fast. How much does Windows itself take to calculate the file size? It should be comparable. Note that after first calculation it should be much faster if you have enough RAM to cache. If it's still too slow for you, the only other software solution I see would be to do some indexing. On Windows, you may try using Windows Search (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779793/query-windows-search-from-java), but that's a bit more involved.

Comment: I forgot about indexing on Windows actually, so I haven't really got anything to compare the speed to, but I can't see much point in so anyway. For the technical reason, like you said, that there is not really much I could do about the speed without getting too technical for the program, and for the simple reason that it is unlikely that the users of my program will be selecting directories that large due to the nature of the application. Thanks once again though!

Answer (score 3):

You are missing an else{} block on the `isDirectory()` if statement. As a result, you are calling `File.length()` on a directory, which is unspecified according to the documentation. It may well be returning a negative value.

Documentation on `File.length()` here:
[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length%28%29)

Your code should probably read:

```
 if(current.isDirectory()) {
    totalLength = totalLength +getFolderSize(current, initial);
  } else {
    totalLength = totalLength + current.length();
  }
```

Comment: @ruakh - Any particular reason you edited out the code sample I put in?

Comment: The code sample wasn't there when I started editing, and the StackOverflow software didn't give me any indication that my edit was conflicting with any other edit.

Comment: @rfeak Thanks for answer, that might have had something to do with it but even when I add an else block it still doesn't work. I didn't think it should make to much of a difference because folders still have a length (file size), don't they?! Anyway, it doesn't really matter now because I know about FileUtils! Thanks again though.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is better stylistically:

```
    private static long getFolderSize(File f) {
        if(!f.isDirectory()) return f.length();
        long totalLength = 0;
        for (File current : f.listFiles()) {
            totalLength += getFolderSize(current);
        }
        return totalLength;
    }
```

Comment: I can't see how that achieves anything. I wanted the total size of a directory, i.e the figure you get when you right click on a folder and press properties. I'm not sure what your code does, but suffice to say not what I want. Anyway, I've found a solution now!

Comment: appologies, I thought you wanted number of files - but it is a trivial change. Updated the code.

Comment: Thanks for the code Robert, that is a nice change but fortunately I have already discovered FileUtils!