# Is there a way of using Windows Indexer information in Java?

Tags: java, windows, indexing

I want to make a crawler-like program that searches a file system and indexes the files [It will have a later use, But that's the main thing i focus on now].

I wonder if there's a way of using the Windows Indexer [Which already have some kind of index] to my use instead of running through the files which can take quite a long time?

Thanks.

Comment: Here is a way via COM+ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779793/query-windows-search-from-java with example

Comment: Thanks. But it's only 'half' a solution. As its only a query - not the actual index. The actual index can save me full file / folders 'branches'.

Answer (score 2):

This might help...

I know its a link to another page... But not having enough reputaion so that i can comment, hence, giving it in answers area..

[Done using Lucene](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/lucene/lucene_first_application.htm)

Hope it might help you...

Comment: It's same as above, Only a partial-solution. Since it's only a query. And querying each file i find through the crawler is just slightly faster than actually scanning the file. The main purpose of using the indexer is saving the crawler some 'scanning branches'. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee805985(v=vs.85).aspx the windows indexing service is no longer supported and encourages anyone interested in carrying out client side search to use the Windows Search SDK https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965362(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Please post related sections here in case web page is changed / removed.

Comment: Thanks for the note @tchrikch and will do so in another answer.. since this   is more of a by-the-way than anything really helpful